# Create Select field in detail window

Tags: extjs, shopware

I am creating a custom plugin where I need to list some stuff in the backend area. Each item in the list has the option to open a detail window where I want to display some info and a **SELECT OPTION** field but not sure how to create it. That field is just to select the option you want and save it in the database.

Is it possible to create it in myplugin/Resources/views/backend/my_plugin/model/product.js file?

I have something like this **(sample)**:

```
Ext.define('Shopware.apps.MyPlugin.model.Product', {
    extend: 'Shopware.data.Model',

    configure: function() {
        return {
            controller: 'MyPlugin',
            detail: 'Shopware.apps.MyPlugin.view.detail.Product'
        };
    },

    fields: [
        { name : 'id', type: 'int', useNull: true },
        { name : 'Name', type: 'string' },
        { name : 'Lastname', type: 'string' },
        { name : 'Date', type: 'date' },
        { name : 'Color', type: 'SELECT?' }
    ]
});
```

Of course the Color field doesnt recognize the SELECT there but I was wondering if there's another word for it?

I was hoping to create that new field like this:

```
fields: [
            ...
            { 
              name : 'Color', 
              type: 'SELECT?', 
              values: {'green', 'blue', 'red'} 
             }
        ]
```

If I am completly wrong could you please guide me where to create this field?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You're defining a model, not a plugin and it looks like you want to configure 'Color' as an enum? Am I right?

The standard types are:

```
Ext.data.field.Field //(Default, implies no conversion)
Ext.data.field.String
Ext.data.field.Integer
Ext.data.field.Number
Ext.data.field.Boolean
Ext.data.field.Date
```

(see documentation under [Field Types](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.2/classic/Ext.data.field.Field.html))

You can probably just use a string unless you want model validation...

You could create a custom type, extended from string or field and use a custom validator. (see same page under [Validation](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.2/classic/Ext.data.field.Field.html))

Example:

```
Ext.define('App.field.Color', {
     extend: 'Ext.data.field.Field',

     alias: 'data.field.color',

     // Match list of colors
     validators: {
         type: 'list',
         list: ['green', 'blue', 'red']
     }
});

Ext.define('App.model.Product', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',

    fields: [
        { name : 'id', type: 'int', useNull: true },
        { name : 'Name', type: 'string' },
        { name : 'Lastname', type: 'string' },
        { name : 'Date', type: 'date' },
        { name : 'Color', type: 'color' }
    ]
});
```